# Como alterar a escala de cores em um gráfico no R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Tenho um gráfico de barras de estados brasileiros. A cor da barra do estado está de acordo com a região que o mesmo pertence.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
A escala de cores foi configurada automaticamente pelo `ggplot2`, gostaria de trocar essas cores, tentei utilizar o `ggthemes`, mas não funcionou.

Código utilizado:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

url <- httr::GET("https://xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/PortalGeral",
                 httr::add_headers("X-Parse-Application-Id" =
                                       "unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm")) %>%
    httr::content() %>%
    '[['("results") %>%
    '[['(1) %>%
    '[['("arquivo") %>%
    '[['("url")

ms <- read.xlsx(url) %>%
    filter(municipio %in% NA)

ms$data <- as.Date(ms$data)

regiao <- ms %>%
    filter(data == max(data)) %>%
    select(regiao, estado) %>%
    unique()

for(i in 9:14) {
    ms[,i] <- as.numeric(ms[,i])
}

rm(url, i)

dados <- read_csv("https://brasil.io/dataset/covid19/caso_full/?place_type=state&is_repeated=False&format=csv") %>%
    select(-c(epidemiological_week, order_for_place, city, city_ibge_code, place_type,
              last_available_confirmed_per_100k_inhabitants,
              is_last, is_repeated)) %>%
    arrange(state, date)

names(dados) <- c("data", "estado", "casosAcumulados", "casosNovos", 
                  "obitosAcumulados", "obitosNovos", "mortalidade", "populacao")

regiao <- ms %>%
  filter(data == max(data)) %>%
  select(regiao, estado) %>%
  unique() 

dados <- merge(x = dados, y = regiao, by = "estado")

dados %>%
  filter(data == max(data) - 1) %>%
  arrange(desc(mortalidade)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = reorder(estado, - mortalidade), y = mortalidade, fill = regiao)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = estado, y = mortalidade, label = paste0(round(mortalidade, 3) * 100, "%")),
            vjust = -0.15, size = 2.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x*100, "%")) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
  labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "solid"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há duas maneiras principais de definir uma escala de cores usando `ggplot2`. Uma delas é manual e outra é utilizando uma paleta de cores pré-definida.

## Definindo cores manualmente

Cada cor deve ser definida manualmente. Essa definição pode ser feita via código (RGB ou hexadecimal) das cores ou pelo seu nome em inglês. A definição via código permite uma variação maior de cores, pois nem todas elas possuem nomes definidos. Se a definição for feita via nome de cores, estes nomes devem estar em inglês. Abaixo eu criei uma escala de cores, que não é necessariamente bonita ou harmoniosa, que permite ver isso em detalhes:

```
dados %>%
    filter(data == max(data) - 1) %>%
    arrange(desc(mortalidade)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = reorder(estado, - mortalidade), y = mortalidade, fill = regiao)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = estado, y = mortalidade, label = paste0(round(mortalidade, 3) * 100, "%")),
                        vjust = -0.15, size = 2.5) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x*100, "%")) +
    scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
    labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10")) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "solid")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", "orange", "cyan"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O R já vem com 657 cores pré-definidas em sua instalação. Seus nomes podem ser consultados através da função `colors()`.

## Definindo cores através de paletas

Basta usar a função `scale_fill_brewer` para definir uma paleta de cores para o seu gráfico. No exemplo abaixo estou utilizando a paleta `Dark2`:

```
dados %>%
    filter(data == max(data) - 1) %>%
    arrange(desc(mortalidade)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = reorder(estado, - mortalidade), y = mortalidade, fill = regiao)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = estado, y = mortalidade, label = paste0(round(mortalidade, 3) * 100, "%")),
                        vjust = -0.15, size = 2.5) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x*100, "%")) +
    scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
    labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10")) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "solid")) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entre no help da função `scale_fill_brewer` para ver quais são as paletas de cores disponíveis no `ggplot2`.

Entretanto, de uns anos pra cá, eu tenho usado uma outra paleta de cores para os meus gráficos. Ela se chama viridis e suas cores são facilmente distinguíveis por daltônicos. Como sou professor, tenho a preocupação de que meus gráficos sejam mais inclusivos e, com ela, meus alunos conseguem diferenciar o que aparece nos gráficos. Além disso, essa escala funciona muito bem em impressões em preto e branco, ao contrário de algumas outras opções de paletas.

```
dados %>%
    filter(data == max(data) - 1) %>%
    arrange(desc(mortalidade)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = reorder(estado, - mortalidade), y = mortalidade, fill = regiao)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = estado, y = mortalidade, label = paste0(round(mortalidade, 3) * 100, "%")),
                        vjust = -0.15, size = 2.5) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x*100, "%")) +
    scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
    labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10")) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "solid")) +
    scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Paletas não-oficiais

Por fim, há paletas de cores não-oficiais, feitas por usuários do R que tem mais noção de teoria de cor do que eu. Uma opção que gosto muito é baseada nas paletas de cores dos filmes do cineasta Wes Anderson e pode ser baixada [aqui](https://github.com/karthik/wesanderson). Sua utilização também é simples e combina os dois métodos vistos anteriormente:

```
library(wesanderson)
dados %>%
    filter(data == max(data) - 1) %>%
    arrange(desc(mortalidade)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = reorder(estado, - mortalidade), y = mortalidade, fill = regiao)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = estado, y = mortalidade, label = paste0(round(mortalidade, 3) * 100, "%")),
                        vjust = -0.15, size = 2.5) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x*100, "%")) +
    scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
    labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10")) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "solid")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Zissou1"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acima criei um gráfico de barras baseado nas cores de [A Vida Marinha com Steve Zissou](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20life%20aquatic%20with%20steve%20zissou%20scenes&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjSlca8_7_pAhXjBLkGHRypDJcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=the%20life%20aquatic%20with%20steve%20zissou%20scenes&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzICCAA6BggAEAgQHjoECAAQGFCeJ1jVLWDhLmgAcAB4AIABqAGIAaQGkgEDMC41mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWc&sclient=img&ei=KNrDXtLhEuOJ5OUPnNKyuAk&bih=698&biw=1280), um dos meus filmes preferidos.

---

Observação: tudo o que foi dito acima para preenchimento de cores (`fill`) pode ser transposto para linhas e contornos (`colour`). Ou seja, basta substituir `scale_fill_brewer` por `scale_colour_brewer` em un gráfico de linha para obter um resultado análogo.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente explicação!

Comment: Disponha. Como não havia informação sobre isso por aqui ainda, achei que seria interessante criar uma resposta o mais completa possível.